# Hibernate, about Persistence layer cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've been reading `Java Persistence with Hibernate`, In this book, it's written in chapter 9 page no. 390 that Persistence Layer cache ensures the following:

**The persistence layer isn’t vulnerable to stack overflows in the case of circular references in a graph of objects.**

Please help me to understand why persistence layer is not vulnerable to stack overflows?

Thank you!

Comment: One presumes it checks for cycles...

Comment: @azurefrog I understand, that it must check for cycles, but I asked the question to know in more details, exactly how Hibernate deals with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find a very definitive answer, but I found something in the Hibernate 3.5 Documentation:

5.2. Hibernate types

5.2.1. Entities and values

In relation to the persistence service, Java language-level objects are classified into two groups:

An entity exists independently of any other objects holding references to the entity. Contrast this with the usual Java model, where an unreferenced object is garbage collected. Entities must be explicitly saved and deleted. Saves and deletions, however, can be cascaded from a parent entity to its children. This is different from the ODMG model of object persistence by reachability and corresponds more closely to how application objects are usually used in large systems. **Entities support circular and shared references**. They can also be versioned.

According to the highlighted line in bold faces, I presume that Hibernate internally checks for such circular referencing and does not load more than one level of nested entity. Much like the case of a Static Class in Java having a Static reference member of its own type.

Comment: I am not accepting my own answer as it is not the exact answer. And someone can  post a better answer about the internal mechanism of Hibernate...